# Docker folder gets duplicated in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Have this Dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
ADD Pipfile.lock /app/Pipfile.lock
ADD Pipfile /app/Pipfile

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile
ENV FLASK_APP=app/http/api/endpoints.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT=4433
ENV FLASK_ENV=development
ENTRYPOINT ["python"] 
CMD ["-m", "flask", "run"]
```

Why in the Docker container my app lands in

/app/app/http/api

App gets duplicated

How to copy it to:

/app/http/api

How can I fix it?

**Update 1:**

My docker-compose and Dockerfile and ls output.

https://0bin.net/paste/ePRws72M#IV8H6iRJ+UMJFr8lB7CRQYKwsnGYflsmOlyvFxZA7zE

Comment: What does the directory structure of `.` on the host machine look like? Any chance you have a structure like `./app/http/...`  Or did you switch source and destination in the copy command? `COPY . /app` copies anything from the current directory on the host to `/app` in the container.

Comment: Yes, that's how it is. How to correct the Dockerfile then?

Comment: `COPY ./app /app`

Comment: Thanks. But it still does not work correctly. If I remove the volumes it copies correctly but then Flask does not response to Requests, does not work :/

Comment: It does copy correctly, but in your docker compose file you are mounting the current directory on the host machine into the container under the mount point `/app` which of course hides the existing `/app` directory within the container ... If you do `ls /app` inside the container, you will see, it has exactly the same content as your project directory on the host machine ...

Comment: if i remove the mounted volume of current dir into /app, everything looks correctly but Flask does not respond to request. With mounted volume there are two /app i.e /app/app/ but it works. No idea why it behaves like this

Comment: Because you are mounting your complete working directory from the host machine under the /app mount point. Therefore /app in the running container of contains everything that is contained in the working directory if your host. And thus, of course also the ./app subfolder, the dockerfile, ...

Comment: Added comment to your answer. Can my it be optimized somehow? Not to have two Dockerfiles, Dockerfile and Dockerfile1 ? Or this is normal?

Comment: If you need two containers, you will need two docketfiles. Although I would strongly suggest not to mix definitions for two docker images in the same directory but keep them separated

Comment: I wanted to start it all with one docker-compose up command. So should i make 2 directories and use 2 docker compose up invocations?

Answer (score 0):

You got two problems here

1. `copy . /app` copies the whole working directory from the host machine into the `/app` directory in the image. If you just want the `./app` subdirectory change that to `copy ./app /app`
2. Your docker-compose mounts the current working directory of the host machine into the container under the mount point `/app` . This hides the existing directory `/app` of the image. So you will either need to copy your app to a different directory or use a different mount point for your volume

Comment: Thanks for your help. This worked: https://0bin.net/paste/1pIU6h9g#DF-W37sjDbUHwzzm89uM7g5rxChMZD87Z3qlHtgLNG1 Is there a way not to use two Dockerfiles ? ie Dockerfile and Dockerfile1?